# Pull id from a list on submit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pull in a list of users from a view model.Then I want to hit the edit button to edit that user.

So I want to post back to the controller to the get method with the user id, so then I can search for the user ID and return the page populated with the data of that user so it can be edited.

I'm having trouble grabbing the id from within the foreach loop. I just want to grab the users id, then send it back so I can find the user.

I have tried to use a hidden for, tried to set the variable within the view.

This is the view model:

```
public class AdminPanelViewModel
    {
        //Just a default constructor
        public AdminPanelViewModel()
        {

        }


        //This constructor takes in two lists so we can collect the data to send to view.
        public AdminPanelViewModel(List<User> users, List<Post> posts)
        {
            this.posts = posts;
            this.users = users;
        }

        public List<Post> posts { get; set; }//Geting a bunch of posts
        public List<User> users { get; set; }//Getting a bunch of Users

        //This is to hold one user from the list
        public User user {get; set;}

    }
```

The View itself, to the foreach loop i'm trying to pull from:

```
@model Blog.ViewModels.AdminPanelViewModel


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AdminPanel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<div class="container body">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

                <h1>Users</h1>
                <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddUser", "Blog")'" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary center-block">Add User</button>

            </div>
        </div>


    <!--This is the begining of the Users Section-->
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Manage User</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Blog", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                <!--This begins the loop through the model to fill in the Users-->
                @foreach (var item in Model.users)
                {

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">@item.FirstName</th>
                            <td>@item.LastName</td>
                            <td>@item.Email</td>
                            <td>@item.UserName</td>
                            <td scope="colgroup">
                               @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.user.UserId, new { Value = item.UserId})

                                <button type="submit" formaction="EditUser" value="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

Where it will post back to:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult EditUser(AdminPanelViewModel adminPanelViewModel)
        {
            int userID = adminPanelViewModel.user.UserId;
            User user = _context.Users.Find(userID);


            return View(user);
        }
```

I want it to go back to get with the userID of the user in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your EditUser method needs to accept your view model, but really just needs the UserId. I would change the method signature to this:

```
public IActionResult EditUser(int userID)
```

and then get rid of the first line, since you already have a userID value.

You could continue to use a Form and the GET method, but that's a little odd. I would use a hyperlink instead, changing this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.user.UserId, new { Value = item.UserId})
<button type="submit" formaction="EditUser" value="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new {userID = item.UserId})
```

Comment: So the new statement creates a new object?